# NVIDIA driver stops responding

Tags: windows-7, drivers, graphics-card

Every now and then my screen goes black and then recovers. On recovery I see the following message on screen.

[image]

It used to happen about once per hour or two but right now is happening every five minutes. I am wondering if this is a hardware or software issue. The device manager tells me my card is an NVIDIA GeForce 8500 GT.

Answer (score 0):

With a card as old as the 8500 GT it really could be either a software problem or a hardware problem. The one possible way to rule it out is uninstall the video drivers then re-install them to see if that fixes the issue.

If it does not fix the issue see if you can temporarily borrow someone else's card that is Nvidia and uses  the same type of interface (AGP or PCI Express). If the problem goes away it was a hardware problem with your card and you need to buy a new card.

If the problem persists I would next try doing a clean reinstall of the OS (testing with both your card and the borrowed one). If the problem persists it is likely a hardware problem with something else in your machine, I would try replacing the power supply first.